# In angularJs 1.5, what is the difference between @ and <?

Tags: angularjs

They are both one-way binding, so what is the difference between them?
@ is for a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Angular website:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

> Inputs should be using < and @ bindings. The < symbol denotes one-way
>   bindings which are available since 1.5. The difference to = is that
>   the bound properties in the component scope are not watched, which
>   means if you assign a new value to the property in the component
>   scope, it will not update the parent scope. Note however, that both
>   parent and component scope reference the same object, so if you are
>   changing object properties or array elements in the component, the
>   parent will still reflect that change. The general rule should
>   therefore be to never change an object or array property in the
>   component scope. @ bindings can be used when the input is a string,
>   especially when the value of the binding doesn't change.